# How to enable SSD TRIM support on Fedora 17?

Tags: linux, fedora, ssd

I used to install Linux on HDD. It's easy. But now I have a SSD, and I want to install Fedora 17 on it.

What should I do to make Fedora 17 issue TRIM commands to the SSD?

Comment: How big is your SSD?  It should work fine.  Did you try installing it already?

Comment: 128GB. It's on my notebook computer.

Comment: So what problem are you having?  Do you need help partitioning?  Help with the bootloader?  What exactly are you asking?

Comment: The Fedora Guide (for 14) has [a chapter on deployment on SSD](http://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/14/html/Storage_Administration_Guide/newmds-ssdtuning.html), is it helpful?

Comment: I don't see any difference on installation, what you expecting, tuning ?

Comment: Well，just like "trim" in windows. How to set "trim" in the Fedora17?

Comment: So your original question should be modified, maybe (note: maybe this article could help http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TRIM#Operating_system_support).

Comment: First make sure you even need trim and aren't just wasting time. Some SSDs don't use it at all, and instead wear-level the entire device whether blocks are in use or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is pretty easy, now that TRIM can pass through LVM to the underlying device(s).

1. When you install, make sure your filesystems are all set to ext4. TRIM is not supported on ext3.
2. After you install, login as root and edit `/etc/fstab`. In the fourth column (that usually reads `defaults`) add the keyword `discard`. Do this for both the `/` and `/boot` partitions, and any other partitions you created on the SSD.

   An example:

   ```
   /dev/mapper/vg_mymachine-lv_root /                       ext4    discard         1 1
   UUID=94b6d32d-ec21-4028-9a89-b1a19849c4ad /boot                   ext4    discard         1 2
   ```

   (If `defaults` is the only keyword there, it can be replaced with `discard`. If other keywords are there, append it with a comma, e.g. `whatever,discard`.)

   Nothing needs to be done for swap; all swap partitions automatically support TRIM.
3. LVM support for discard is disabled by default. Enable it by editing `/etc/lvm/lvm.conf` and changing `issue_discards = 0` to `issue_discards = 1`.
4. Restart the computer.

Answer (score 1):

There were some problems in Fedora 18 with LUKS not propagating TRIM commands,
but this was fixed in Fedora 19. On my system, TRIM commands propagate
successfully. One just needs to make few changes in the configuration. First
of all, we need to check if TRIM propagates for all partitions to the end
device:

```
[lzap@lzapx ~]$ lsblk -D
NAME                                            DISC-ALN DISC-GRAN DISC-MAX DISC-ZERO
sda                                                    0      512B       2G         1
├─sda1                                                 0      512B       2G         1
└─sda2                                                 0      512B       2G         1
  ├─fedora_lzapx-root                                  0      512B       2G         1
  ├─fedora_lzapx-swap                                  0      512B       2G         1
  └─fedora_lzapx-home                                  0      512B       2G         1
    └─luks-aaaaaaaa-6657-44f4-8297-bbbbbbbb1111        0      512B       2G         0
```

The last column shows if TRIM commands do propagate. We can see all is set,
*except* the encrypted home (the last line). To get full TRIM support on
LUKS-encrypted devices, we need to allow TRIM commands. Note that *this can
decrease encryption strengh*. This is the Fedora 19 default crypttab file:

```
$ cat /etc/crypttab
luks-aaaaaaaa-6657-44f4-8297-bbbbbbbb1111 UUID=aaaaaaaa-6657-44f4-8297-a571e02e5492 none
```

I added `allow-discards` option there:

```
$ cat /etc/crypttab
luks-aaaaaaaa-6657-44f4-8297-bbbbbbbb1111 UUID=aaaaaaaa-6657-44f4-8297-a571e02e5492 none allow-discards
```

### Optional LVM configuration

If you modify your LVM logical volumes often (e.g. shrinking, deleting), you
want to set issue_discards to 1 in `/etc/lvm/lvm.conf. Then you need to do 
the next optional step described bellow.

### Optional init RAM disk regeneration

If you have *root* partition encrypted by LUKS (not my case) or if you have 
your *root* partition on LVM *and* you want LVM trimming when shrinking or 
deleting (see above optional step), initial RAM disk needs to be regenerated 
using the following command:

```
dracut -f
```

You will need to reboot to make this change effective of course.

Now, to enable TRIM and take advantage of it, there are two options:

### TRIM when deleting files

It is possible to configure ext4 to send TRIM commands while deleting data.
You can do this by adding `discard` option to partitions in `/etc/fstab`. Note
that this slows down deleting a bit. It depends on the SSD drive, but this can
slow down quite significantly on some drives.

Do not put `discard` option to swap devices as this is not required (and
perhaps it will not work either). Swap is SSD friendly by default and
propagates TRIM command.

### TRIM from cron

This is the preferred option because it can be scheduled daily, weekly or
during night if you do not turn off your laptop/server:

```
cat /etc/cron.weekly/01-fstrim
#!/bin/sh
fstrim /
fstrim /home

chmod +x /etc/cron.weekly/01-fstrim
```

Try to run the script now, it should not print any error message. If you
changed LUKS configuration, you might need restart before doing that.

http://lukas.zapletalovi.com/2013/11/how-to-trim-your-ssd-in-fedora-19.html

Comment: If your _root_ filesystem is encrypted, you must do this and then rebuild your initramfs by rerunning `dracut` before it will take effect for the root filesystem.

Comment: Yes, it is not as you can see from the above `lsblk` command. I made a note in my blogpost tho. And also changed the answer not to confuse googlers - thanks!